# Spring MVC for portlets, request lifecycle

Tags: java, spring, request, portlet, lifecycle

does anybody know where to get documentation about Spring request lifecycle for portlet App (Spring's annotation based controller?

I need to know the order of calling methods by Spring and parameters (request, model, ...) available on each stage of request handling.

Main question is: when @ModelAttribute methods are called (I want to see full picture, not just "after that, before that", which I've already got via debugging)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What version of Spring are you using?

Comment: I think that the `DispatcherPortlet` source code is quite easy to follow - https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc-portlet/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/portlet/DispatcherPortlet.java

Answer (score 0):

If you see the Spring documentation about Portlet MVC you'll not find any clear picture (a real picture of rows and boxes) of its workflow but on the beginning of the [Web MVC framework chapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) you have some rough picture of the different phases of the lifecycle. Portlet MVC is introducing some extra to the Web MVC but it basically works otherwise the same way as Web MVC.

What Spring Portlet introduces more to this is the rendering phase after the action phase that alters the database and makes the business level stuff while the render phase then handles what comes actually on the display.

Answer (score 0):

@ModelAttribute methods are called before the action phase, which precedes the render phase. So for example on an @ActionMapping method, where the model is a form backing object, the @ModelAttribute annotated method will be called to initialise the model, then the model on the request will be used to update it with anything that the user has changed. This is handy as it saves you the trouble of finding the model manually before saving it.